# Play Spotify playlist or album music in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

> Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=1 "The operation failed due to an unspecified issue." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation failed due to an unspecified issue

Here is my code

```
func getAlbums(authSession:SPTSession){

    SPTPlaylistList.playlists(forUser: authSession.canonicalUsername, withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken) { (error, response) in
        if let listPage = response as? SPTPlaylistList, let albums = listPage.items as? [SPTPartialPlaylist]{

            for item in albums{
                let stringFromUrl =  item.uri
                // use SPTPlaylistSnapshot to get all the playlists
                print("************************\(item.name)************************")
                SPTPlaylistSnapshot.playlist(withURI: stringFromUrl, accessToken: authSession.accessToken!) { (error, snap) in
                    if let s = snap as? SPTPlaylistSnapshot {
                        print("====================\(s.name)=====================")

                        // get the tracks for each playlist
                        SpotifyManager.MyAlbums.append(s)
                        if SpotifyManager.MyAlbums.count == albums.count{
                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: relodNotification), object: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This error comes from this method**

```
@objc func play() {

    print(songInfo.uri)
    SpotifyManager.player?.playSpotifyURI(self.songInfo.uri.absoluteString, startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (err) in

        print(err.debugDescription)

    })
}
```

if anybody face this type of problem please give me the best solution to play the Spotify music in my app.

Comment: you're repeating the list by looping while there's no looping, the player takes the list and handles the looping itself

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the looping because the player does that automatically for you!

Comment: But I have to show list of all albums or playlist and when click on particular album or playlist will show list of all songs of this playlist after that I'll click on particular song and play for the same.

So that I needed Looping.